how to scroll to the bottom in richtextfx TextArea
I'm trying to create a text area that whenever a text is added, it will scroll to the bottom. With the help of ChatGPT and all the documentation I could find, I ended up with this, but it doesn't work.
    import javafx.application.Application
    import javafx.application.Platform
    import javafx.scene.Scene
    import javafx.scene.control.Button
    import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane
    import javafx.scene.layout.Priority
    import javafx.scene.layout.VBox
    import javafx.stage.Stage
    import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea
    
    class MainApp : Application() {
    
        override fun start(primaryStage: Stage) {
            // Create a StyledTextArea to act as the console
            val console = InlineCssTextArea().apply {
                isWrapText = true
                isEditable = false
            }
    
            // Wrap the console in a ScrollPane to make it scrollable
            val scrollPane = ScrollPane(console).apply {
                isFitToWidth = true
                isFitToHeight = true
                hbarPolicy = ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER
                vbarPolicy = ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS
            }
    
            var line = 1
    
            // Create a button to simulate adding text to the console
            val button = Button("Add Colored Text").apply {
                setOnAction {
                    Platform.runLater {
                        console.appendText("New line added to console at ${line++}" + "\n")
                        scrollPane.vvalue = 1.0
                    }
                }
            }
    
            val vbox = VBox(button, scrollPane).apply {
                VBox.setVgrow(scrollPane, Priority.ALWAYS)
            }
    
            // Create the Scene
            val scene = Scene(vbox, 600.0, 450.0)
    
            // Set up the Stage
            primaryStage.title = "JavaFX Console"
            primaryStage.scene = scene
            primaryStage.show()
        }
    }
    
    // Entry point for the application
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        Application.launch(MainApp::class.java, *args)
    }

Moreover, the scrollbar looks as if it is empty. I can only scroll with the mouse wheel.
What am I doing wrong?

Maybe you should consider tagging your question with Kotlin. Kotlin-people will search for Kotlin tagged questions and not for javafx tagged ones. :)
